# Adversarial noise level regarding input normalization

Tags: deep-learning, normalization, standardization

I've been implementing adversarial attacks and defenses these days, and it is important to precisely mark the adversarial noise level, what we usually call as `ε` in relation to the input scale e.g. `[0, 1]` or `[0, 255]` for images.

However, the problem is when we treat the public data like MNIST or CIFAR-10, there're known (mean, std) vectors for each dataset and while we normalize (z normalize or standardize) the input with these vectors like below,

```
(input - mean) / std
```

the input values are no more scaled to `[0,1]` rather goes to about `[-0.5,2.7]` for MNIST in my case and the network is trained with these values, not `[0, 1]`.

In this case, How should I properly write the epsilon values **to compare with the ones in other papers scaled with `[0, 1]` or `[0, 255]`**

My first thought was writing `ε` as `ε / std` when the original input values, `x` were scaled within `[0, 1]` since

```
x' + ε' * noise = {(x - mean) / std} + ε' * noise, where x' and ε' are normalized value
                = {(x + ε * noise) - mean} / std, where x is scaled within [0, 1]
∴ ε' = ε / std
```

Is that right?

Also, as far as I know, it is practically good to do z-normalize to fastly or efficiently guarantee the convergence of weight of the network by [LeCun's paper](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf). but I'm curious whether people are really doing z-normalization on image data such as MNIST or CIFAR-10 especially treating adversarial examples.